# Quicksort remove some of the conditions

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

```
public static void quickSort(Integer[] arr, int low, int high) 
    {
        //check for empty or null array
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0){
            return;
        }

        if (low >= high){
            return;
        }

        //Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[middle];

        // make left < pivot and right > pivot
        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) 
        {
            //Check until all values on left side array are lower than pivot
            while (arr[i] < pivot) 
            {
                i++;
            }
            //Check until all values on left side array are greater than pivot
            while (arr[j] > pivot) 
            {
                j--;
            }
            //Now compare values from both side of lists to see if they need swapping 
            //After swapping move the iterator on both lists
            //NUMBER (1)
            if (i <= j) 
            {
                swap (arr, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        //Do same operation as above recursively to sort two sub arrays
        //NUMBER (2)  
        if (low < j){
            quickSort(arr, low, j);
        }
        //NUMBER (3)
        if (high > i){
            quickSort(arr, i, high);
        }
    }
```

I'm a beginner in quicksort algorithm. Can someone tell me what is the purpose of the conditions namely if number(1), if number(2) and if number(3) in the quicksort algorithm above?

For Number(1), the condition I feel is not necessary because i will definitely be smaller or equal than j and therefore the swap should just execute.

For Number(2) and Number(3), it is the similar explanation. Please correct me if i'm wrong thank you

Comment: Can you give me a sample of unordered array element to prove that i can be greater than j which executes the swap incorrectly so that i can visualize. thanks

Comment: Actually it looks like as this is currently written, `i<=j` will always be true at `NUMBER (1)`. I don't think this algorithm is correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 - the two former `for` loops just check for the right elements to swap (from left and right side) so when the `i` and `j` index positions are calculated,  this condition see if they are in a position that needs to be swapped (because implicitly one is greater than another).

Number 2 and 3 - these are part of the "Divide and conquer algorithm", this part just split the array in two smaller parts.

Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#/media/File:Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif) (source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort))

Comment: I understand the divide and conquer approach. However, i feel that i will always be less than j and low < j and high > i. Therefore, it is not necessary to put those conditions. Please give me a counter example to disprove this if possible thanks

Comment: No, sorry, this is not right way. I suggest that you debug this code step by step and study the algorithm, there are plain of documentation, posts and video that explain it in detail.

Comment: The idea of pivot in the quick sort is the breakthrough that let this algorithm to be better than others.